# "pure virtual method called terminate" in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using tf.data.Dataset API to build a data pipeline, I encountered an error in training:

```
pure virtual method called terminate 
called without an active exception 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What's worth noting is that the error did not occur at the beginning but actually the middle of the training process(after 4800 epochs). Here is how I build the pipeline:

```
import tensorflow as tf

epochs = 30000
eval_step = 400
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# code to read and process data

features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(train_features.dtype, train_features.shape)
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(train_labels.dtype, train_labels.shape)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder, file_list_input))
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size_placeholder)
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=1)

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder, file_list_input))
val_dataset = val_dataset.repeat()
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size_placeholder)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes) 
features, labels = iterator.get_next()

train_iterator = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)
val_iterator = iterator.make_initializer(val_dataset)

# code to build model
for i in range(epochs):
    sess.run([train_iterator, ... # other ops],
             feed_dict = {[features_placeholder: train_features,
                           labels_placeholder: train_labels]})
    if (i%eval_step)==0:
        sess.run([val_iterator, ... # other ops],
             feed_dict = {[features_placeholder: val_features,
                           labels_placeholder: val_labels]})
```

Has anyone had the same issue? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I met probably the same problem with tensorflow 1.12, and solve it after upgrade to 1.13. good luck!

Comment: When training your model, how many data do you have? I suspect it's because tf.data.Dataset can't handle a large amount of data.